# Use ngRoute resolve to pass variable to component

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

After reading some nice stuff about angularJS 1.5 components, I'am trying to start using it.
I did a simple test trying to have a "Hello world!" component with the "world" being a binding.
I would like to use ngRoute to pass that data to the component, but I didn't manage to do it. I searched but didn't find a solution.

Here's the code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<component1></component1>',
        resolve: {
          name: 'world'
        }
    });
});

app.component('component1',{
    template: '<h1>Hello {{$ctrl.name}}!',
    bindings: {
        name: "@"
    }
});
```

I tried with different bindings like "<" and "=" without success.
Please also note that it is working if I pass the variable in the template like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<component1 name="world"></component1>'
    });
});
```

Here's a plunker that reproduces the issue I have: https://plnkr.co/edit/Aq9wbUi6rZe4hFoFOa31?p=preview

Your help would be highly appreciated ;)

Cheers,
Jerebenz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), you should understand that

- the values of the resolve object are supposed to be functions
- the resolved values are not directly bound to components. They're available in the template scope's `$resolve` variable.

So the code should be

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<component1 name="{{ $resolve.name }}"></component1>',
        resolve: {
          name: function() { return 'world'; }
        }
    });
});

app.component('component1',{
    template: '<h1>Hello {{$ctrl.name}}!',
    bindings: {
        name: "@"
    }
});
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/rMx2SymR6GXT51Souxgt?p=preview for a demo.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, I understood resolve should be a function and also tried to use $resolve in the template, but I didn't put the {{}}. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There is still something I don't understand (I am not sure if I should post a new question) that is why I cannot use '<' binding in this case (I think it is because it is a string) and how can I use '<' (so how can I pass an object if my assumption is correct)

Comment: What if your component already has a controller? How do you get the resolve dependencies into it?

Comment: @Jerinaw the reoslved name is provided as a binding to the component, so you can access it using `this.name` in the controller of the component: https://plnkr.co/edit/E9NZfMH4zxFiZ5pGAel9?p=preview

Comment: Yea, I figured it out after I commented. It's attached tot he controller instance not the $scope :-/ Thanks!